# How to generate hash512 in pre-request from request that has {{variables}} in uri

Tags: javascript, hash, postman

So I m working on API when i need to set x-auth header for every request in PRE-REQUEST script.

I have variables in my request url i.e `{{baseUrl}}{{basePath}}{{businessID}}/users?name={{userName}}......etc`

I need to take whole address and add `secretKey` variable to the end of address, then get hash512 from it.

I was able to achieve that if i have no variables in my address i.e.: `dummy.com/12321-e213-21-3e?name=John`

I did this by :

```
var secret = "1234qwerHr2";
var url = request.url.slice(9); //sliced because I don't need to include baseUrl to hash

var hashedPayload = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(CryptoJS.SHA512(url+secret));
```

This will return the desired result.

Here is what I logged when trying the same code with variables

```
console.log(url); =>>>>>>> asePath}}{{businessID}}/users?name={{userName}}......etc
```

All variables defined , that`s for sure

Basically question is : how to get url with values of variables using `var url = request.url;` I need not `{{businessID}}/users?name={{userName}}` but `12321-e213-21-3e?name=John`

Answer (score 0):

I lost source where i found it. Somewhere on postman github issue thread

```
var secret = pm.globals.get("devSecretKey");

pm.myUtility = {
    interpolateVariable: function (str) {
        return str.replace(/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/g, function (match, $1) {
            // console.log(match)
            let result = match; //default to return the exactly the same matchd variable string
            if ($1) {
                let realone = pm.variables.get($1);
                if (realone) {
                    result = realone
                }
            }
            return result;
        });
    },
    getUrl: function () {
        let url = pm.request.url.getRaw();
        url = this.interpolateVariable(url)
        let {
            Url
        } = require('postman-collection')
        return new Url(url);
    },
    getUrlTest: function () {
        let url = pm.request.url.getRaw();
        url = this.interpolateVariable(url)
        // let {
        //     Url
        // } = require('postman-collection')
        //return new Url(url);
        return pm.request.url.parse(url);
    }

}

var requestPath = pm.myUtility.getUrl().getPath();
var requestQuery =pm.myUtility.getUrl().getQueryString();
var hashedPayload = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(CryptoJS.SHA512(requestPath+"?"+requestQuery+secret)); //I added '?' because when you use getQueryString() i does not have '?' before query 

pm.environment.set("tempAuthHash", hashedPayload);// use this in your header
```

This function he wrote is converting your {{variable}} to 'variableValue'
No need to change anything in his functions if you are not good with coding. Guy who created it has golden hands. Just place in your pre request